# Using attributes for output filenames in QGIS Process Modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, labeling

How can I use process inputs (eg: Table field) inside an expression for an output file when using Process modeler?

I have a process which outputs a raster, whose output filename should be the value of one of its attributes. When I select "Use Expression..." when executing the process, I try to use `@filename_value` but the preview shows only `"`. The fields and values category in the expression calculator shows `NULL`.

So how can I output multiple files using attribute fields as filenames within process modeler?

Here's the process I've made:

[image]

And the expression editor:

[image]

Comment: It's not currently possible (2.18 and 3.0)

Comment: Rather: It is possible with qgis-processing (pyqgis) code/scripts, but not using the process modeler.

Comment: @Senshi do you have an similar/example script I can refer to?